# Moment startOf day rounds to next day

Tags: momentjs

Why

```
moment('2019-01-01T23:00:00+00:00').startOf('day')
```

returns

```
"2019-01-02T00:00:00.000"
```

And how do I remove the time from the equation altogether so that it returns exact date without rounding?

Comment: `moment('2019-01-01T23:00:00+00:00').startOf('day').subtract(0, "days")`

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Please note that the [suggested](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) way to [display](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) a moment object is using `.format()`, `.toString()` or `.toISOString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your timezone.

`moment('2019-01-01T23:00:00+00:00')` gives you a moment object in your timezone. For example, if you are in GMT+2 zone, formatting will be like:

> 2019-01-02T01:00:00+02:00

If you use `startOf(day)` function for that moment object, the result will be:

> 2019-01-02T00:00:00.000

To overcome this, if you are dealing with UTC timezone, simply use `utc()` function.

```
moment.utc('2019-01-01T23:00:00+00:00')
```

Formatting of this function will be like (depends on your local):

> 2019-01-01T23:00:00Z

Start of day of above date gives you:

> 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z

In order to remove time section, use your own format in `format()`:

```
moment.utc('2019-01-01T23:00:00+00:00').startOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

```js
let myLocalDate = moment('2019-01-01T23:00:00+00:00');

console.log('Date in your timezone:', myLocalDate.format());
console.log('Start of date in your timezone:', myLocalDate.startOf('day').format());
console.log('---');

let myUtcDate = moment.utc('2019-01-01T23:00:00+00:00');

console.log('Date in UTC:', myUtcDate.format());
console.log('Start of date in UTC:', myUtcDate.startOf('day').format());
console.log('---');
console.log('Only date part:', myUtcDate.startOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```